# Modal window only pulling information from first record in a PHP for each loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a page with a foreach loop which shows data for a set of parks. The foreach loop runs fine. Within that loop I have a button which you push to get a modal window to show additional information on that park. The button itself knows where it is in the loop (I've labeled it with a variable as a test) but when the modal window opens it only brings up information from the first record.

```
foreach ($showresult as $display)
{
$display_result[] = array        ('parkid' =>$display['parkid'],
                                    'trailsys' =>$display['trailsys'],
                                    'state' =>$display['state'], 
                                    'trailset' =>$display['trailset'],
                                    'name' =>$display['name'], 
                                    'description' =>$display['description'], 
                                    'url' =>$display['url'], 
                                    'ldes' =>$display['ldes'],
                                    'ltxt' =>$display['ltxt'],
                                    'address' =>$display['address'], 
                                    'city' =>$display['city'], 
                                    'zip' =>$display['zip'], 
                                    'phone' =>$display['phone'], 
                                    'pos' =>$display['pos'],    
                                    'T1' => $display['T1'],
                                    'T2'=> $display['T2']);}

$states = get_states($variable);
    foreach ($states as $staterow) {
        $state_set[] = array ('id' =>$staterow['id'],
                                  'st' =>$staterow['st'],
                                      'state' =>$staterow['state'],
                                      'reg' =>$staterow['reg']);
    }
?>


<html>
    <head>
...
</head>
    <body>

...


<?php foreach ($display_result as $parkrow) {   ?>
        <!-- FEATURES HEADING -->
        <div class="row" id="featuresHeading">      
            <div class="col-12">    
<h2> <?php echo $parkrow['T1']; ?> </h2>
<h2 id="subtitle"><?php echo $parkrow['T2']; ?></h2>
<p class="lead"> <?php echo $parkrow['description']; ?> </p> 
            </div><!--close col-12 -->
        </div><!-- close featuresHeading -->

        <!-- PANEL GROUP -->

<div id="dom-target" visibility: hidden> 
<?php $output = $parkrow['description'];
      echo htmlspecialchars($output); ?>
</div>

        <!-- PANEL 1 -->
        <div class="row" id="features">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo "location of " . $parkrow['name']; ?></h3>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
                            data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php $parkrow ?>">Open modal for <?php echo
                             $parkrow['name']; ?></button>
                        </div><!-- close panel-heading -->
                            <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                            <p>Click Here for Location</p>
                    </div><!-- close panel -->
                </div><!-- close col-sm-4 -->

...

        <!-- MODAL WINDOW -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4>This is a test</h4>
                            </div><!-- close modal-header -->

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="$name">
                                    </div><!-- close form-group -->

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                                    </div><!-- close form-group -->
                                </form><!-- close form -->
                            </div><!-- close modal-body -->

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                            </div><!-- close modal-footer -->
                        </div><!-- close modal-content> -->
                </div><!-- close modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- close modal -->  

<?php
unset($parkrow);
 } ?>    ...
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var myData = div.textContent;
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-header').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(myData)
})
```

To see it in action: http://www.ride4wheel.com/test_site/ride.php?id=pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the DOM-ID '#exampleModal' several times in your html.
You should have only ONE #exampleModal and then update it as you did.
So put the 'Model' out of the php-loop!

Comment: Makes sense. So I moved the modal window outside the loop, but I'm still having the same trouble.

Comment: next: you don't have anything in the data-whatever attribute of your buttons defined. (its empty)

Comment: I'm trying to have the php variable"<?php $parkrow['name'] ?>" in there. Code above says <?php $parkrow ?> (I was attempting to pass the array and then work with it in the JS script. No luck either way What's better to try? The end goal is to get several of the fields from $parkrow to pass in to the modal window.

Comment: <?php echo $parkrow ?>
the 'echo' is missing!

Comment: Nearly there, but here is one odd thing - it works, but only passes the first word of the entry. For instance if the park name is "Slippery Dunes" it is only passing "Slippery". Any ideas?

Comment: you need to wrap your "data" in ""!
like
data-whatever="<?php echo $parkrow ?>"

Comment: Wrapping a variable in quotes throws a syntax error.

Comment: The issue was that I need to use url encode. Now I just need to find out how to make it use spaces instead of +. I'm sure I can find that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the php-variables in quotes, but the html-attributes.
note, that the quotes are outside of the php-tags!

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="container pb-video-container rounded">
        <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="./image/play.jpg" alt=".." width="2.4%" height="5%" style="border-radius:20%;"> Derniers Films </h2> 
        <!-- ************************************************************************************************ -->
        <?php 
           include_once "./inc/ViewMain.php";

           $currentViewer = new ViewMain;
           $rslt = $currentViewer->viewAll();
           foreach($rslt as $elm) {
        ?> 
        
        <div class="movie-card card col-sm-3 col-md-3 pb-video">
           <div class="margPadCard pb-video">
              <div  class="modal fade" id="<?= $elm["idf"] ;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0 iframe">
                          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
                             <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?= $elm["video"] ;?>" autoplay=0 mute=1 volume="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                          </div>
                       </div>                        
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <a href="#">
                 <img src="<?= $elm["pochette"] ;?>" class="img-fluid z-depth-1 card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?= $elm["idf"] ;?>" alt="..." width="100%" height="340">
              </a>
           
              <div class="pmain movie-content pb-video">
                 <div class="movie-titleC movie-content-header">
                    <a href="#">  <h4 class="text-center form-control label-warning"><b><?php echo $elm["titre"] ;?></b></h4>  </a>
                    <div class="imax-logo"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="movie-info">
                    <div class="info-section">
                       <label><?php echo $elm["realisateur"] ;?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="row">
                       <div class="info-section col-sm-6">
                          <label><?php echo $elm["pays"] ;?></label>  <span> - <?php echo $elm["langue"] ;?></span>
                       </div>
                       <div class="info-section text-right col-sm-5">
                          <label><?php echo $elm["categorie"] ;?></label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

https://wpbeaches.com/creating-a-loop-of-bootstrap-modals/?unapproved=318184&moderation-hash=e1deea02c06790e5ed1e1b0b5ff16e31#comment-318184

Comment: When posting an answer please give clear explanation, this one only has a code snippet and a link. Even if it's solves the question perfectly I really dislike that you just put code and a link without even writing a single sentence